How do I convert a ddrescue map file to a badblocks list for fsck, with partitions?
I have run ddrescue on a disk that has multiple partitions.
One of these partitions is an ext4 file system, and several files inside that didn't make it because they have bad blocks. I'd like to give the list of blocks that couldn't be copied to fsck -l, so it is aware of the damage.
Is there a readymade tool that can parse the map file, adjust the list of lost blocks by partition offset, and convert to file system block numbers?
